# Navigating the DOM: What is this elements relationship to this one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form page where each field is validated as each form input is changed. When a field is invalid, the user sees a red error message.

I'd like to capture these error messages for analytics purposes (How are people progressing through our sign up funnel). I'm doing this using a change listener on the form field

In the example below the error message is the text content of `#authCreateAcctPasswordErrorTxt`, "Your password must be at least 6 characters long." (Right at the bottom of the code block).

The event listener is on the input element with id "authCreateAcctPasswordInput". So in relation to that element, I must grab the text content of what appears to be it's cousin or something like that, the text of span with id "authCreateAcctPasswordErrorTxt".

I have a little (but not much) experience using `.parent(), .siblings() and .children().` I'm sure I could use those to navigate where I need in relation to the input field `#authCreateAcctPasswordInput`.

But that could look long and messy. Is there a neater way?

Here is the HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <label for="create-password">
    Enter Password (at least 6 characters)
  </label>
  <span id="authCreateAcctPasswordDiv" class="pwdiv">
    <input class="f-left" type="password" id="authCreateAcctPasswordInput" value="" maxlength="70" name="createPassword" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
  </span>
  <span id="authCreateAcctPlainTextPasswordDiv" class="pwdiv" style="display: none;">
    <input class="f-left" type="text" id="authCreateAcctPlainPasswordInput" value="" maxlength="70" name="passwordClear">
  </span>
  <div class="f-left-chkbx">
    <span class="sqChbx beside">

      <input type="checkbox" id="authCreateAcctShowPassChkBox" name="showPassword">

      <label for="authCreateAcctShowPassChkBox" class="labelOver">
      </label>
    </span>
    <label for="authCreateAcctShowPassChkBox">
      Show
    </label>
  </div>

  <span class="clearfloats">
  </span>
  <span id="authCreateAcctPasswordErrorTxt" class="Error" style="">
    Your password must be at least 6 characters long.
  </span>
</fieldset>
```

And here is what I tried:

```
$('#authCreateAcctPasswordInput').parent().siblings('.Error').text()
```

But in the console that returned `""`

How to I get "Your password must be at least 6 characters long." returned in relation to #authCreateAcctPasswordInput?

Comment: How about you get the id, which is unique, other than the class: `siblings('#authCreateAcctPasswordErrorTxt')`

Comment: @Rooster ah, yes there is. There are 4 now that I look at the rest of the doc. I'll need to adjust and tell the script which one based on logic

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes I need to change this, closing

Comment: have you tried `$('#authCreateAcctPasswordInput').parent().next('.Error')`?

Comment: got it with a little more trial n error: $('#authCreateAcctPasswordInput').parent().siblings('.Error').text()